# Why doesnt my textview show up when I add autolayout constraints?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have a view which contains a textview (which displays a question) at the top. And 4 labels (for various answer options) with a stack of option buttons at the foot.

When leave the 'question' textview without constraints it appears fine in portrait. When I rotate the handset the text doesnt expand across the width of the screen.

I thought the way to resolve this was to click the add constraints pin/align button and click the T bars adding '0' constraints for top trailing and leading.

However when I do that the textview doesn't display at all. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: What do your errors say (the red arrow next to `Question View Controller Scene`)?

Comment: It says: Missing constraints: Need constraints for: Y position, height

Comment: I have a similar issue except I actually added a bottom constraint and it still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The height constraint is missing. When you don't provide any constraints to your UITextView Xcode automatically will add the constraint's but as soon as you try to pin the top, leading and trailing anchors Xcode will not add any constraint's automatically.

You have to pin the bottom anchor of the UITextView to any of your buttons or give it a height constraint will solve your problem. Because UITextView will not calculate it's height based on it's inner content size like UILabel or UITextField.

If you want to only display some text and no edit functionality then you can use a UILabel and set the number of lines to 0.

Comment: I added a constraint to top, bottom, left, and right, and it doesn't show up at all.

Comment: @TimothySwan do you use UITextView or UILabel? if you're using UITextView you have to set an height constraint as well

Comment: I am using a UITextLabel. I am unsure why one would need to set a height constraint if they are already setting a top and bottom, but even if it needs to be done, it would need to fit all devices. I cannot just put a hardcoded number in for a height, but that is the only option I have seen thus far. Do you see a relative option for height which will automatically adjust to fit the device screen?

Comment: if you're using labels then you don't need to set the height constraint it will set the height of the label automatically based on your text. don't forget to set the labels number of line to 0 and if you're creating the label in code then you have to set labels translatesAutoresizingmask to false fill fix your problem